# importance of scalarizing weights in quality of Pareto solutions of multi-objective optimization problems

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a multi objective optimization problems, basically I need min f1(x) and min f2(x). I have read that one solution would be to scalarize it like
    f(x)= w1*f1(x)+w2*f2(x), w1,w2>0 and find the min f(x). 
It was said that the solution x0 of the single - objective  min f(x) is guaranteed to be a Pareto solution of the original problem. My question is the following: For different sets of values of w1 and w2 we will obtain different Pareto solutions x0. Are these solutions x0 equivalent between them in terms of "optimality"? Can we say that one of them is better than the other? And if yes, how one can choose weights w1 and w2 in order to get the best Pareto x0?

Comment: If you knew (or had some formula for) the 'correct' way to weight the two objectives, then you wouldn't really have a multiple objective problem. The  choice of different weights will give you different trade-offs between the two objectives, but all those Pareto solutions should be equally valid and equally 'good'. If you inspect those solutions and find preferences for some solutions over some others, then you have some reasons to choose those. You could then of course try to include those criteria in your objective...

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick - ok, but there is something that I did not fully understand. You said that the different Pareto solutions are "equally good", but then you say that one can find preferences of some solutions over some other. What could be these preferences? What do you mean? If one can find criteria to prefer other solutions then they are not equally good since just some solutions qualifies? How can be measured the degree of "fitness" of a solution?

Comment: I said 'IF you find preferences'. Only you or your users can decide if there may be some other criteria that would make one of other solution preferable. If it really is true that all those Pareto solutions are equally good, then it doesn't matter which you choose. BUT if you then discover new criteria for choosing between those Pareto solutions, you could then add those new criteria. It can be a useful process interacting with users and showing them many 'equally good' solutions as it can help uncover previously hidden assumptions and preferences.